# How to have the image width wise always 100% but height cropped from both ends dynamically

Tags: jquery, css, crop

I have portfolio items thumbnails but all in different sizes. How i can make the image width wise always 100% but height cropped from both ends dynamically?

Here is the html sctructure

```
<div class="portfolioimagebg" style="background:url(http://xxxxxxxxxxx.jpg);background-size: cover;background-position: center center;width:100%;background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div>
```

Is that possible?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, here you are using background-size:cover so your image should always feat the `div` size. Can you give an example ?

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correctly this code will do approximately the same thing

```
#section1 {

    background: url(../images/Components.jpg) no-repeat center center;

    background-color: rgb(40, 75, 99);

    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(50, 75, 99, .8);

    background-size: cover;

    color: #fff;

    min-height: 800px;

}
```

Just remove /edit the min-height for your need, this code was used to cover an entire div scaling on all devices if you need width try using min-width:100%;

Comment: With background-size am getting the peace of the image not fully

Comment: Oh I see you want it to stretch I'll take a look

Comment: I dont to strech them, the all issue is with that that i dont want to strech them. Is there a way?

Comment: Are you sure that the image aspect ratio is correct. If your aspect ratio is different from the website, the image will not be fully shown just partially so it fills the screen

Comment: Here is the webiste link http://ipointnew.ipoint.com.mt/creations/ - so you could check the thumbails

Comment: I am on mobile now so hard to determine, but add that link to your question. And by using width 100% and no height value for img and div containing images the images should be displayed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you can use `background-size: 100%` and `background-position: center`.  Then your background will always be 100% width and centered in the div.  Here is a fiddle [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/evathg8c/)

Comment: by doing how you are telling i am having top and bottom part empty I need image fullwidth but automatically adjusted with height

Comment: Then you need to use background-size:cover instead of 100% but this will not have your image 100% it will cover the div so it may be like 120% width of the div.  If you are having the top and bottom empty with background-size:100% then you will want to use background-size: cover.  Changing the image to always be a width of 100% and then dynamically filling the rest of the div will result in skewed images and make your images look bad.  So I think your best bet here is to go with background-size: cover and backgroun-position: center.

Comment: With that option i will have the peace of the image not fullwidth, is there a way of having either fullwidth and height adjusted @Drinkin People?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with dynamically?

If you need discrete interval ( something like Desktop/Tablet/Mobile ) you can use the CSS Media query.

If you need continuous interval ( like the window size ) you have to do it in javascript or some other scripting language.

Anyway [there is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DrSRT/567/) using media query. It just set a fixed height that change at some breakpoint ( in this case for windows with < 760)

```
.portfolioimagebg{
 height: 300px
}

@media screen and (max-width:760px){       
   .portfolioimagebg{
     height:100px;
 }
}
```

For more information about media query [see this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Comment: Saying dynamically i mean automatically not depending on uploaded imag e width or height